Bonaire Durango Window Evaporative Swamp Cooler 4500E (2022) High speed only works. Last year all ok--Low, Med and High. Capacitor? Easy to replace?
Bonaire Durango Window Cooler 4500E (2022) High is only working speed, Last year was fine-Low, Medium and High. Capacitor? Easy to replace yourself?
I just cleaned it and removed control knob when I did. Wondering if I put it back incorrectly.
Tried removing and returning again, but no luck.

Please post a photo
